# Java Array Reverse

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

This is my first question here.
So The thing is...I would like to understand, how could I reverse an array, that contains objects, without using Array.java.utils and a Temporary array.

```
    public void reverse() {

    Ball [] ballsTemp = new Ball[balls.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.length / 2; i++) {
        ballstemp[i] = balls[i];
        balls[i] = balls[balls.length -1 - i];
        balls[balls.length -1 - i] = ballstemp[i];
    }
}
```

So this is **not** what I want ^

Comment: What is `notas`?  Why is your temporary variable an array?

Comment: without a temporary variable or without a temporary array?

Comment: My bad sorry. it was mean to be balls. So we are working with a balls[ ] ;

Comment: Why don't you wan't to use a temporary variable?

Comment: sorry! I mean balls.length and Temp Array.

Comment: You don't need a temporary array, but you do need a temporary variable. With an integer array it can be done without one, due to bit-trickery, but you can't do that with objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temp variable instead of a temp array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < balls.length / 2; i++) {
    Object temp = balls[i];
    balls[i] = balls[balls.length -1 - i];
    balls[balls.length -1 - i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: I think, You helped a lot! Ty. That easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a temporary array, you could use a Stack instead.

```
Stack ballsTemp = new Stack();
for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
    ballsTemp.push(balls[i]);
}
for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i] = ballsTemp.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Stack instead, here is a very simple example:

```
  Integer[] intArray = new Integer[5];
  intArray[0] = 3;
  intArray[1] = 6;
  intArray[2] = 9;
  intArray[3] = 12;
  intArray[4] = 15;

  Stack<Integer> intStack = new Stack<Integer>();
  for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
      intStack.push(intArray[i]);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
      intArray[i] = intStack.pop();
  }
```